# Why does Chrome console.log display String objects in such an annoying way?

Tags: javascript, string, google-chrome, object, console

Primitive strings show up nicely in the Chrome console. But String objects come out like this:

```
s = new String('foo bar')
==> String {0: "f", 1: "o", 2: "o", 3: " ", 4: "b", 5: "a", 6: "r", length: 7, [[PrimitiveValue]]: "foo bar"}
```

I know I can see it more prettily with `s+''` or `s.toString()`. But I often need to look at arrays and other structures full of these things. So I get the less-than-helpful:

```
[s,s,s]
==> [String, String, String]
```

And when I expand one of the Strings, I get a vertical representation of the whole character array.

If there's no good answer, maybe someone could at least commiserate with me.

Comment: `console.log([s,s,s].map(String))` will clean it up for you... i used `s+0` back in firebug to coerce a string primitive without pressing [SHIFT].

Comment: Thanks for the map suggestion. I don't think you can add methods and other properties to primitive strings. That's why I use Objects.

Comment: do you mind if i ask why you use "new " in front of string variables? (i've actually never seen anyone do that before and i'm wondering what you get from doing so, if you're not too busy)

Comment: Also, I like to be able to all the other (own) methods and properties of the Strings I'm looking at. I just want the actual contents of the String to not be so messy.

Comment: s=String('foo') gives you a primitive string. You need new to get an Object.

Comment: thanks for the follow-up, noted and appreciated.  do note that you can modify String.prototype to add methods to both primitives and StringObjects. If you mean own properties, you need an object, but most would use {id:445, section: "main", content: "this is my text"} instead of plopping them on string objects, which can be problematic (eg JSON), and are more memory
 intensive than char sequences... Still, interesting idea, and who doesn't want smarter text? ;) you could make a single String prototype getter that coerces to a primitive, so you can say `objString.raw` and get back a primitive.

Comment: Maybe it's hopelessly wrong headed, but I've made this tool for manipulating Javascript data that I love and use all the time. It's in some flux at the moment, but maybe a quick look at the unfinished docs will explain why I need overloaded String objects: http://sigfried.github.io/blog/supergroup/

Comment: i didn't mean to shake your confidence or criticize your approach, and it sounds like you have good reason, not accidental confusion. i just really love JS and was curious about using it in a novel manner. tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cheeky answer is that Chrome displays it that way because that is what the String object is. Would it make sense for Chrome to try and cast any old object to a primitive?

Dandavis comments are right on the money - depending on your use, you may be able to modify the String prototype, then use primitives for readability and rely on the [primitive being cast to a String object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) (thus making your methods available):

> JavaScript automatically converts primitives to String objects, so
>   that it's possible to use String object methods for primitive strings.

e.g.

```js
String.prototype.upper = function () {
    return this.toUpperCase();
};
document.write("foo bar".upper());
```

If you really wanted to, you could write a similar object like this:

```js
function MyString(value) {
    this['[[PrimitiveValue]]'] = value;
    this.length = value.length;
    for (var i = 0;i<value.length;i++) { this[i] = value.charAt(i); }
    this.charAt = function(val) {
            return this[val];
        };
    this.toString = function() { return this.primitive };
    return this;

}
var myString = new MyString('foo bar');
var string = new String('foo bar');
document.write('custom:', myString, ' native:', string, '<br/> check the console too');
console.log('custom:', myString, ' native:', string)
```

which will output something like this to the console:

```
MyString {0: "f", 1: "o", 2: "o", 3: " ", 4: "b", 5: "a", 6: "r", [[PrimitiveValue]]: "foo bar", length: 7, charAt: function, toString: function}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following the cheeky answer. The contents of a String object are an array of characters, but so are the contents of a string primitive, aren't they? So, why, in the object's case, should the console tediously show us every character separately? Also, I don't want to munge up the global String prototype. If Javascript allowed me to subclass String in a decent way, a lot of my headaches would disappear. In the meantime, I'm loading up individual String objects with methods and properties, which works, but is kind of ugly.

Comment: The primitive is not the same as the object - e.g. `new String('hello') === 'hello'` >false but `new String('hello') == 'hello'` >true because without strict equality, JavaScript will cast one (I believe the primitive is cast to a String) and then compare them. If you could access it (but you cannot) the `new String('hello')[[primitive value]]` would be equal to the primitive 'hello'. This may help... http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.5 this may be better: http://vicfriedman.github.io/blog/2013/09/15/the-difference-between-javascript-primitive-data-types-and-objects/

Comment: another way to look at it is `typeof "hello"` > `string` and `typeof new String("hello")` > `object`. The console shows each character separately in the object because that is how the String object internally maintains its state to facilitate easy access to parts of the string like `charAt()`...

Comment: I don't know if that's quite right. My understanding of the documents you linked above is that, although the String object's data is stored in its [[primitive value]], which is basically a `string`, the object also makes each character available as a property (0:"f",1:"o",2:"o"). So, the only reason `"foo"[0]` evaluates to "f" is because "foo" gets cast to a String object, which does its magic of adding a length property, a 0 property ("f"), etc. So, as useless as it is to see these properties in the console, I guess Chrome is just being honest when it displays them.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying isn't quite right - but your summary accurately states what is happening.  I was trying to say above - they are not the same (primitive vs String object) and the only reason you can treat them the same is because the primitive is cast to the object under the covers. The console.log of the String object is showing you the internal representation of the object "Chrome displays it that way because that is what the String object is" (from the answer).

Comment: FYI. the MDN link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String and quote in the answer is the documentation showing where the primitive is cast to the object.